# General PHP TWIG conventions

Tags: php, templates, twig

I've a simple PHP news application. It's not MVC, just procedural PHP. However, I am thinking about using Twig for frontend. I have been reading the documentation and some things are not clear to me.

In the Twig-documentation you see the code below as how to send variables to the template.

```
<?php
echo $template->render(array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));
?>
```

But my template contains over 50 variables. How to keep it readable?  Repeating the line above for every variable or create one big array to pass it to the template? What are best practices for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render function takes an array as argument. In this example you're creating the array while calling render function. In real application you will create associative array with data and then just pass it as argument

Comment: Yes, I get it. So for example if have several functions which returns all kind of data, building up the associative array. And at the end of the file I pass the whole array to Twig->render().

Comment: Yeah exactly. You can pass array as reference in php